# How to get full webpage HTML in c#?

Tags: c#, html, ajax, selenium, web-scraping

I am attempting to make a webscraper to collect news articles however I am having trouble obtaining the full html content of the webpage. [Here is the url](http://www.fa-mag.com/search.php?and_or=and&date_range=all&magazine=&sort=newest&method=basic&query=ubs) that I initially need to scrape for article search results:

Then, I scrape each individual article ([example](http://www.fa-mag.com/news/the-paradox-of-choice-in-alternative-investments-33418.html)).

I have tried using WebRequest, HTTPWebRequest, and WebClient to make my requests, however the result that is returned each time only contains the html content for the sidebar, etc. I have used Chrome developer tools and the returned html begins just after the main content of the page, and therefore is unhelpful. I also have looked for ajax calls for the content and have not been able to find any.

I have successfully been able to scrape the needed content using Selenium Webdriver, however this is not ideal as it is much slower to visit every url, and it often gets hung up loading pages. Any help with requesting the full html contents of the page would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you added the code you are running

Comment: If you're not getting the HTML you need to scrape with your initial request, chances are it's being loaded with JavaScript. In which case, you need to replicate those requests to get what you need.

Comment: You are getting raw html for article links. From what I can see you must send the query argument http://www.fa-mag.com/search.php?query=u&offset=0 if the query param is left empty it returns nothing.

Comment: I have already sent the query argument. The url is correct

Comment: Have you tried [NSoup](https://nsoup.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what issue you having, but here's how I accomplished your task.

First I viewed the page in my web browser with the network tab open in developer tools.

From here I collected a list of headers my real browser sent. I then constructed an HttpWebRequest appending the subsequent headers and was able to retrieve the full html of the page.

```
public string getHtml()
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.fa-mag.com/search.php?and_or=and&date_range=all&magazine=&sort=newest&method=basic&query=ubs");

    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0";
    req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    req.Headers.Add("cookie", "analytics_id=595127c20cdfe6.52043028595127c20ce022.71834842; PHPSESSID=tbbo7npldsv26n2q7pg2728k77; D_IID=3E4FEA7F-9794-34EE-99F8-87EEA3DF0689; D_UID=5F374D94-270D-3653-8C54-9A46F381EAE2; D_ZID=505BB8EF-5A2D-3CBD-87D8-FABAD5014776; D_ZUID=BB0C9EF2-0E7B-383E-A03A-A3E92CC8051A; D_HID=9642D775-D860-3F04-8720-73E5339042BA; D_SID=63.138.127.22:6Ci6jv2Xv+yum3m9lNfnyRcAylne67YfnS/u8goKrxQ");
    req.Headers.Add("DNT", "1");
    req.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
    HttpWebResponse res = null;
    try
    {
        res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (WebException webex)
    {
        res = (HttpWebResponse)webex.Response;
    }

    string html = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    return html;
}
```

Without the custom headers, there is bot protection on the page that sends a 416 response and does a redirect. If you read the html in the redirect page it states the site has detected you as a bot.

Comment: You are right but most likely the session will expire and you will be declared a bot again. Might need to make two calls for the redirect.

Comment: I just ran this same code and still only received the partial html of the page

Comment: here is the html I get: Edit, too long can't paste it here.

Comment: does it begin with sidebar or right skyscraper? that's where mine begins when I run your code, which is after the main content section

Comment: additionally, your code stops working entirely after several minutes when the session expires as @FilipCordas mentioned above. is there any way to reliably get the full html content without having to send a unique cookie?

Comment: I get the following: https://pastebin.com/xaXyjADd This issue is as you stated the session, You will need to keep track of the response headers and update cookies on subsequent requests as needed.